# Building web app on Azure: npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm trying to build a Node.js website on Azure. During the deployment I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200

npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.12.6\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\2.11.2\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"

npm ERR! node v0.12.6

npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2

npm ERR! path D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\socketio-jwt\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\node_modules\jws\node_modules\base64url\node_modules\meow\node_modules\indent-string\node_modules\repeating\node_modules\is-finite\node_modules\number-is-nan\package.json.5f81d88f6c51ba4596881f5ad60cfe9c

npm ERR! code EINVAL

npm ERR! errno -4071

npm ERR! EINVAL, rename 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\socketio-jwt\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\node_modules\jws\node_modules\base64url\node_modules\meow\node_modules\indent-string\node_modules\repeating\node_modules\is-finite\node_modules\number-is-nan\package.json.5f81d88f6c51ba4596881f5ad60cfe9c'

npm ERR!

npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:

npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log

Failed exitCode=-4071, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.12.6\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\2.11.2\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production

An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

[[Full log here]](http://pastebin.com/xBAEXhsK)

My app was uploaded to Azure [[this way]](https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/) (through a git)

Any ideas what could go wrong? On my computer, application runs very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More likely than not, the path is too long. I believe the max path length on Windows is 255 characters or so. The `rename()` path in the log output is 276 characters.

Comment: Yeah, you could be right. Do you know what can I do now? I mean: I can't rename it "just like that" because it won't be working correctly :/